# Related to Activity addition to manifest in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is it compulsory to add a class file, which extends activity, to manifest?

I have created a java file for handling file IO and to use openfileoutput() openfileinput() i have extended Activity class.

Comment: yes yes yes yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use/call that class (which extends Activity) somewhere in your code, you MUST declare that class (Activity) in Manifest file. If you don't, you will get exception.
Manifest file is used to declared essential information for your app (Activity, Service, Broadcast Receiver, keys,...).
For more info about Manifest, you can check it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

Answer (score 1):

YES you most declare it in the manifest so the application will know its activity.

Answer (score 0):

when you launch the application first the OS will check your manifest file.So if your Activity is not Listed in the Manifest file.Then it won't execute it.So your ACTIVITY class should be declared in the Manifest file.